# Problem in creating route via set of Coordinates using HERE Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, here-api, points

I am using HERE maps SDK for creating route with set of coordinates. For this I am using following code:

```
var linePoints = [[String:Any]]()
self.linePoints = [["lat":37.33292,"long":-122.01026],["lat":37.33305,"long":-122.01058], 
["lat":37.33336,"long":-122.01104],["lat":37.33376,"long":-122.01144], 
["lat":37.33375,"long":-122.01144],["lat":37.33372,"long":-122.01147], 
["lat":37.33368,"long":-122.01156],["lat":37.33367,"long":-122.01172], 
["lat":37.33369,"long":-122.01183],["lat":37.33385,"long":-122.01208], 
["lat":37.33389,"long":-122.01217],["lat":37.33389,"long":-122.01227], 
["lat":37.33388,"long":-122.0123],["lat":37.3338,"long":-122.01232], 
["lat":37.33369,"long":-122.01241],["lat":37.33383,"long":-122.01263], 
["lat":37.36421,"long":-122.06282],["lat":37.36461,"long":-122.06286], 
["lat":37.36526,"long":-122.06301],["lat":37.36567,"long":-122.06313], 
["lat":37.36632,"long":-122.06341],["lat":37.36702,"long":-122.06381], 
["lat":37.37243,"long":-122.06709],["lat":37.37282,"long":-122.06732], 
["lat":37.37314,"long":-122.06747],["lat":37.37353,"long":-122.06761], 
["lat":37.37396,"long":-122.06773],["lat":37.37452,"long":-122.06782], 
["lat":37.37628,"long":-122.06425]]
var waypoints = [NMAWaypoint]()
    var geocordinates = NMAGeoCoordinates()
    for (index,dict) in self.linePoints.enumerated() {
        geocordinates = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(dict["lat"] as! Double), 
longitude: CLLocationDegrees(dict["long"] as! Double))
        if (index == 0) || (index == self.linePoints.count - 1) {
            waypoints.append(NMAWaypoint(geoCoordinates: geocordinates, waypointType: 
.stopWaypoint))
        } else {
            waypoints.append(NMAWaypoint(geoCoordinates: geocordinates, waypointType: .viaWaypoint))
        }
    }
```

Used below function to calculate route:

```
 coreRouter.calculateRoute(withStops: waypoints, routingMode: routingMode1) { (routeResult, error)
```

**Problem:** It creates route with lot of loops (180 degree turns or rotation) in the route. I am passing waypointType ".stopWaypoint" for first and last co-ordinate and ".viaWaypoint" for rest of the co-ordinates. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try replicating the example using the steps mentioned in the following documentation : https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/import-route.html

Please write us back incase you still getting multiple turns with the following coordinates. Map matching API can be also be used to see where the coordinates are exactly lying in the map or are they crossing each other while forming a route